# Android UI: Looking to drawing an expanding ciricle

Tags: android

I am in need of a good resource like a tutorial or sample code that would draw an expanding circle of different thickness.  To be exact, a small full circle that would expand and shrink over time like a few seconds.

Thanks for the help.

I am relatively new on this and so I would like to ask for help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This class will help:

```
public class BallView extends View {

public float x;
public float y;
private final int r;
public int color;

public void setColor(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
}

@Override
public float getX() {
    return x;
}

@Override
public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

@Override
public float getY() {
    return y;
}

@Override
public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getR() {
    return r;
}

private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);


//construct new ball object
public BallView(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
    super(context);
    //color hex is [transparncy][red][green][blue]
    mPaint.setColor(0xFF15FFD4);  //not transparent. color is white
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;  //radius
}

//qcalled by invalidate()
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
}

}
```

You can use it to draw a ball in your main activity using `mainView.addView(mBallView)` to add it to the view and `BallView.invalidate` to actually draw it and according to whatever mechanisms you want to achieve you can use the setter method to set the radius of the circle as time increases or whatever you'd like. Make sure to use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) that calls `RedrawHandler.post()` within it and redraws the view within there with the updated radius values.